# Speed up my function - Dynamic button creation vb.net

Tags: vb.net, performance, button, dynamically-generated

I have a function that creates button dynamically based on a database table, there are about 250 records inside. Everything is working properly but I'd like to make it faster but I don't know how.

Maybe it's due to the language I don't know.

Actually, on my development machine, it takes about 56 seconds to load. I'm not an experienced developper so maybe I'm missing something.

The problem is that on the client machine, that has only 4Go of RAM, the loading time is much bigger, 2.5 to 3.5 minutes.

Thans you for your help.

This is my code :

```
Public Sub LoadProducts()

    Me.ProgressBar1.Value = 0
    Me.ProgressBar1.Visible = True

    Dim oSim As New SimFonction
    Dim str As String = "SELECT * FROM produits ORDER BY ref;"
    Dim oCmd As New MySqlCommand(str, oSim.ConnectDb)
    Dim oData As New DataSet
    Dim oAdapt As New MySqlDataAdapter With {
        .SelectCommand = oCmd
    }
    oAdapt.Fill(oData)
    oSim.conn.Close()
    recCount = oData.Tables(0).Rows.Count
    Dim btn(recCount) As Button
    Dim x, y, j As Integer
    oAdapt = Nothing
    oCmd = Nothing
    str = Nothing

    Dim ref As String
    x = 0
    y = 0
    Dim valeurIncr As Integer = 100 / recCount
    valeurBar = 0
    i = 0


    For i = 0 To oData.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        If Me.ProgressBar1.Value >= 90 Then
            Me.ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        End If
        If j = 5 Then
            y += 90
            j = 0
            x = 0
        End If
        x += 90
        btn(i) = New Button With {
            .Parent = productPanel,
            .Location = New Point(x, y),
            .Height = 90,
            .Width = 90,
            .Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14, FontStyle.Bold),
            .ForeColor = Color.Orange,
            .UseVisualStyleBackColor = True,
            .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter
        }
        ref = oData.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("ref").ToString

        If IsDBNull(oData.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("photo")) Then
            btn(i).Text = oData.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("ref").ToString
            btn(i).Tag = oData.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("ref").ToString
            btn(i).Name = "bt" & ref
        Else
            Dim photoP As New IO.MemoryStream(CType(oData.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("photo"), Byte()))
            btn(i).BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(photoP)
            btn(i).BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
            btn(i).Tag = oData.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("ref").ToString
            btn(i).Text = oData.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("ref").ToString
            btn(i).Name = "bt" & ref
            photoP = Nothing
        End If

        If oSim.CheckProduiEnStock(ref) = False Then
            btn(i).Enabled = False
        End If
        AddHandler btn(i).Click, AddressOf ButtonClicked
        j += 1
        Me.ProgressBar1.Value += 1
        btn(i) = Nothing
    Next
    Me.ProgressBar1.Visible = False


End Sub
```

Comment: About the only thing I can see is your handling of the memorystream for photoP.  Wrap that in a using clause maybe.  Other than that everything else seem pretty straightforward.  Try stepping though you code to find what is taking so long.  And you will need to review your usage of progress bars.  What you’ve got here probably won’t work as you intended.

Comment: Maybe also try the code review stack.  Probably better suited to this type of question

Comment: Thank you for the advices I will check this today and let you know if things work better.

Comment: Redrawing the user interface on every iteration is a main slow down. The FlowPanel might save some positioning code. Take heed of the answer by @Miguel.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following command:

At the beginning: `Me.SuspendLayout()` ,and 
at the end: `Me.ResumeLayout()`